# How to show a dynamic clock on master page?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I tried it and searched a while on Google but there are the examples which are very complicated for me. I want to show a clock on my master page which should be dynamically. I am not much familiar with `Jquery` and all the examples I got there are with `Jquery`. So is there a simple way for a beginner to use that digital clock on master page. I also want to show the blink of the colon per tick which will separate the time.

Comment: Are you trying to display the server time or the time the client has on his/her machine?

Comment: I want to show the Client time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making a simple clock with javascript is not that difficult.

Have a look here for an example:
[example](http://www.metalshell.com/source_code/85/Javascript_Display_Current_Time.html)

I changed the example in the link a little so it's easier to read and perhaps to understand:

```
  <input type="text" id="clock"/>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    setInterval("settime()", 1000);

    function settime() 
    {
      var dateTime = new Date();
      var hour = dateTime.getHours();
      var minute = dateTime.getMinutes();
      var second = dateTime.getSeconds();

      if (minute < 10)
        minute = "0" + minute;

      if (second < 10)
        second = "0" + second;

      var time = "" + hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second;

      document.getElementById("clock").value = time;
    }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an ajax panel. Have a look about the easy to use [ajax update panels](http://ajax.net-tutorials.com/controls/updatepanel-control/) online and then you could have the clock expand by one second each tick (they have a timer control) although im pretty sure that you could find a freebie somewhere that does something like that for you.

[This link](http://basgun.wordpress.com/2008/02/27/realtime-dynamic-clock-using-aspnet-ajax-updatepanel/) seems pretty simple to me.

EDIT

in view of the client side needs and the comment below, you could also try [this link](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jclock)

Comment: Ajax panel seems like a lot of overhead simply to display the time. You'd need an ajax call every second.

Comment: True, however i was taking in to account the fact that jquery is not simple enough for our subject.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar version that does your colon tick. Note that it uses jQuery simply to perform the colon 'fade'.

```
function clock(){
  var d = new Date();
  var h = d.getHours();
  var m = d.getMinutes();
  var s = d.getSeconds();
  $('#clock').html(h+"<span class='colon'>:</span>"+m+"<span class='colon'>:</span>"+s);
  $('.colon').fadeTo(1000, .2);
  setTimeout(clock, 1000);
}

<div id="clock"></div>
```

You can modify the values that are inside your message, such as adding a month/day/year, etc simply by using the Date object as I have done.